# How to use subquery result as the column name of another query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to use the result from subquery as the column name of another query since the data changes column all the time and the subquery will decide which column the current forcast data stored. My example:

```
select item,
      item_type
      ...
      forcast_0 * 0.9 as finalforcast
      forcast_0 * 0.8 as newforcast
from sales_data.
```

but the **forcast_0** column is the result (**fore_column_name**) of the subquery, the result may change to forcast_1 or forcast2

```
select 
     fore_column_name 
     from forecast_history 
     where ...
```

Also, the forcast column will be used multiple times in the first query. how could I implement this?

Comment: you can create a view of the sub query or use the sub query as a temp table.

Comment: Can you please post the entire query you are running?

Comment: @user1578653, Hi the entire query is very long, sorry i am not able to post all of them on here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your sub query as an inline table. Something like....

```
select item,
       item_type,
       ..
       decode(fore_column_name, 'foo', 1, 2) * 0.9 as finalforcast,
       decode(fore_column_name, 'foo', 1, 2) * 0.8 as newforcast
  from sales_data,
       (
          select fore_column_name
            from forecast_history 
           where ...
       ) inlineTable
```

I'm assuming here that the value from the sub-query will be the same for each row - so a quick cross-join will suffice. If the value will vary depending on the values in each row of the `sales_data` table, then some other type of join would be more appropriate.

Quick link to [decode](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php) - in case you aren't familiar with it.

Comment: actually i do want to use the returned value instead of column name. But the returned value will decide which column it will be used in the first query